# ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid?

Tags: ubuntu

I'm trying to build and compile some package with bitbake for Dreambox image.
With ubuntu 20.04 no problem.
But after upgrade to 21.04 I have got this error with compile.

```
Log data follows:| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 8 ARCH=arm64 CONFIG_MALI_MIDGARD=m CONFIG_MALI_MIDGARD_DVFS=y CONFIG_MALI_PLATFORM_DEVICETREE=y CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-oe-linux- DEPMOD=echo INSTALL_MOD_PATH=/home/raed/build_image/OpenPli-DM/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/build/tmp/work/dreamtwo-oe-linux/meson-mali-module-bifrost-r12p0/201901-0-gd4a30ca-r0/image M=/home/raed/build_image/OpenPli-DM/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/build/tmp/work/dreamtwo-oe-linux/meson-mali-module-bifrost-r12p0/201901-0-gd4a30ca-r0/meson-mali-module-bifrost-r12p0-201901-0-gd4a30ca/bifrost/r12p0/kernel/drivers/gpu/arm/midgard -C /home/raed/build_image/OpenPli-DM/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/build/tmp/work-shared/dreamtwo/kernel-source EXTRA_CFLAGS=-DCONFIG_MALI_PLATFORM_DEVICETREE -DCONFIG_MALI_MIDGARD_DVFS -DCONFIG_MALI_BACKEND=gpu
| make: Entering directory '/home/raed/build_image/OpenPli-DM/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/build/tmp/work-shared/dreamtwo/kernel-source'
| make[1]: Entering directory '/home/raed/build_image/OpenPli-DM/openpli-dreambox-oe-core/build/tmp/work-shared/dreamtwo/kernel-build-artifacts'
| 
|   ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.
|          include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.
|          Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.
|
```

I have tried some solutions but without luck to solve it !!!

current kernel is (5.11.0-34-generic)

Comment: You probably need to supply the complete path to the autoconf.h file - typically the file it's located somewhere under /usr/src.

Comment: I have found it in this path (/usr/src/linux-headers-5.11.0-34-generic/include/generated/autoconf.h) ..... What after ?!!

Comment: But did you follow the instructions which were provided to fix the problem in the error message?

Comment: The compile run with bitbake not manually ..So I can not fix it with manual compile

Comment: Read the bitrake manual for building a kernel. It's still a LInux system and "make defconfig" should still generate a kernel configuration. Then the manual should tell how to configure bitrake to find the configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered the same problem with you when I compile my own kernel module in yocto.

I fix this problem by adding "inherit module-base" in my own bb file.

For more details, you can see the module.bbclass in poky/meta/class/
and you can find the defination of module-base in the following url:
https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.7/ref-manual/ref-manual.pdf